# Grab element in list based on variable name in R

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a list such as the following:

```
mylist = list(a="one",b="two",c="three")
```

Suppose I want to grab the value of the variable named `"a"`, I can do something like this:

```
myvar = "a"
mylist[toString(myvar)]
```

But suppose I have a list of variable names, and I want to grab all the values, for instance

```
names = c("a","b")
```

`mylist[toString(names)]` does not work, but basically, in theory, it should return a vector `["one", "two"]`. How can I get this to work? I'm thinking to use `tapply` or `lapply` or something like that, but I can't quite figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply use `mylist[names] ` and `mylist[myvar]`

Comment: `mylist[names]` will return `list(a = "one", b = "two)` to get a vector you need `unlist(mylist[names])`

Comment: `toString` doesn't work because you don't need that function here at all. Read its documentation to see why.

Comment: Seems this should be closed "as no longer reproducible".